# jQuery Remove Spaces in Element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am setting a DIV id dynamically with a custom field that a user will type in on the backend of a WordPress site. For example: "Section Title". How can I remove the spaces of "Section Title" and set the DIV ID to: "SectionTitle"?

Current output = `<div id="Section Title"></div>`

Desired output = `<div id="SectionTitle"></div>`

I have been able to replace the spaces in console.log(); but can't replace them inside the DIV ID itself.

```
var myText = jQuery('.full_width_content').closest(".cent_full_width").attr("id");
var newMyText = myText.replace(/ /g,'');
```

Comment: After doing `var newMyText = myText.replace(/ /g,'');` do not you do `jQuery('.full_width_content').closest(".cent_full_width").attr("id", newMyText);` ??

Comment: fix it on the data-entry side or the data output side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You have to replace `old-id` with this `new-id` (what you are getting through your code)***

```
var myText = jQuery('.full_width_content').closest(".cent_full_width").attr("id");
var newMyText = myText.replace(/ /g,'');

// remove older id and place new id
jQuery('.full_width_content').closest(".cent_full_width").at‌​tr("id", newMyText);
```

***A sample example:-***

```js
var myText = jQuery('.full_width_content').closest(".cent_full_width").attr("id");
var newMyText = myText.replace(/ /g,'');

// remove older id and place new id
jQuery('.full_width_content').closest(".cent_full_width").attr("id", newMyText);
```

```css
#SectionTitle{/* to show you that code is working fine */ 
  color:green;
  font-size:30px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cent_full_width" id="Section Title">
  <div class="full_width_content">Hi</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.replace(/\s/g, '');` to remove the spaces and then set id using `attr()` **jQuery**.

```js
// Remove the spaces
var str = $(".test").attr("id").replace(/\s/g, '');

// Then set the id with spaces removed
$(".test").attr("id", str);

// You can check at console
console.log($(".test").attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="Section Title"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

attr() is both the setter and the getter. Simply reference the id attribute within itself, as the second line below.

```
var myEl = jQuery('.full_width_content').closest(".cent_full_width");

myEl.attr("id", myEl.attr("id").replace(/\s+/g, '');
```